# extracting color from object in qtp

Tags: qtp

I've an object(which is a window) and it has many regions of colors in it. is there a way qtp can extract only the color from a specific region in that window. GetROProperty and currentStyle.color cannot be used since it will give the color of the whole window. I only need the color of a specific region in that window.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the X and Y coordinates of an object through the `abs_x` and the `abs_y` (for the position on the desktop) or `x` and `y` (for the position in the parentwindow). Through the external lib located in gdi32.dll, you can use the `GetPixel(hDC, X, Y)` function.

hDC is the Device Context and you can get it by calling the external function `GetWindowDC(hWnd)` from the user32.dll. You need a Window Handle, that can be extracted from the `hwnd` property of the Window or Desktop object (depending if you are using `abs_x/y` or `x/y`).